# set empty value to a text field by deselecting checkbox

Tags: php, checkbox, textfield

I have a form with 2 text fields that trigger a jquery date picker.

I want to set empty values to both text field by unchecking a checkbox that is in the same form.

The text fields are:

```
<?php 
   if ($_GET["arrival"]== "") 

   echo ' 
   <label for="arrival">Arrival </label>
   <input type="text" name="arrival" class="w8em format-d-m-y highlight-days-67 range-low-today" id="arrival" value="Select Date"/> ';

   else

   echo ' 
   <label for="arrival">Arrival </label>
   <input type="text" name="arrival" class="w8em format-d-m-y highlight-days-67 range-low-today" id="arrival" value="' . $_GET["arrival"] . '"/> '; 
   ?>

<?php

   if ($_GET["departure"]== "") 

   echo ' 
   <label for="departure">Departure </label>
   <input type="text" name="departure" class="w8em format-d-m-y highlight-days-67 range-low-today" id="departure" value="Select Date"/> ';  

    else

    echo ' 
    <label for="departure">Departure </label>
    <input type="text" name="departure" class="w8em format-d-m-y highlight-days-67 range-low-today" id="departure" value="' . $_GET["departure"] . '"/> '; 
    ?>
```

The checkbox is:

```
<input name="avail" type="checkbox" id="avail"
                 <?php if ($_GET["avail"]== "1") echo "checked=\"checked\""; ?>
                 value="1" />
```

I want by deselecting it to set empty values to text fields.

Comment: You want to do this with jQuery (client-side) or PHP (server-side)?

Comment: if your goal is for controlling user input, then, its not a good idea, you can show empty form when $_GET["avail"] != 1

Comment: You really shouldn't output user supplied data without any validation and sanitization. At the very, very least you should use `htmlspecialchars($_GET["arrival"])` in your context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery for make it working.

checkbox  `onclick event` you can set empty value for textfield.

```
<script>
        function empty()
        {
           if($("#avail:checked").length > 0)
           {
              $('#arrival').val('');
              $('#departure').val('');
           }
        }
</script>
```

Add onclick event on checkbox

```
<input name="avail" type="checkbox" id="avail"
             <?php if ($_GET["avail"]== "1") echo "checked=\"checked\""; ?>
             value="1" onclick="empty();"/>
```

Comment: I had to change the if ($_GET["avail"]== "1") to "0" as it was clearing the fields on checking it.

how can i uncheck it when setting dates to the text fields?

Comment: means when you setting dates to the text field you want checkbox will be unchecked ?

Comment: yes, correct. I want when dates are set the ckeckbox to be unchecked.